# use javascript to access form element on different page

Tags: javascript, forms, action

Is it possible to get a form elements value using javascript if the action goes to a different page?
Here are snippets of code to illustrate what I'm trying to do:

index.html:

```
<form name="testMe" action="show_music.jsp" method="get">
<p>I am interested in these types of music:</p>
<select id="music" name="music" multiple>
            <option value="classical">Classical</option>
            <option value="christian">Christian</option>
            <option value="alternative">Alternative</option>
            <option value="rock">Rock</option>
            <option value="latin">Latin</option>
            <option value="pop">Pop</option>
            <option value="disco">Disco</option>
            </select>
```

show_music.jsp

```
<p>Here are the music styles you like: </p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var e = document.getElementById("music");
    var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    alert("Var is: " + value);
</script>
```

I've been trying different combinations of trying to get the values of that select list, but no luck.  Is it even possible?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this cases it's better to use server-side to gather the value, so if possible, use POST instead of GET, using JSP (and you can pass the value to Javascript easily):

```
alert('Var is: <%=request.getParameter("music")%>');
```

Or if you can't/don't want to use POST, use query string parsing like some suggested

Comment: Well, I can't believe I overlooked the jsp!  This is what I came up with:

    String[] music = request.getParameterValues("music");

    for (int i = 0; i < music.length; i++) { 
 out.println(music[i] + "<br>");
    }

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the value from the element, as it doesn't exist any more, but as the form sends the data to the new page, you can pick it up from the query string:

```
var value = querystring("music")[0];
alert("Var is: " + value);

function querystring(key) {
   var re=new RegExp('(?:\\?|&)'+key+'=(.*?)(?=&|$)','gi');
   var r=[], m;
   while ((m=re.exec(document.location.search)) != null) r.push(m[1]);
   return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your form is getting submitted via GET method, perhaps you can try something like this:

```
var params = [];
var split = location.search.replace('?', '').split('&')
for (var i=0; i++; i<split.length) {
    params.push(split[i].split("="));
}
```

This will give you a list wherein every list item will be another list consisting of the first item as the key and the second item as the value. For example, http://google.com/?abc=def&xyz=123

will give something like:

```
[
    ["abc", "def"],
    ["xyz", "123"],
]
```